# Count the number of elements of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
var answers = [];

answers[71] = {
    field: 'value'
};

answers[31] = {
    field: 'value'
};

console.log(answers);
```

This outputs the **length** of the array as **72** but I was expecting it to return **2**. Here's the output of the script from chrome console:

[image]

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Since you were defined index `71` which creates array of length `72` and remaining elements would be undefined

Comment: the real script i am working on will need to work with arbitrary indexes in the array as per example. How would I go about counting the actual number of elements in the array?

Comment: `answers.filter(function(v){return true;}).length;` ,  filter wouldn't itertate over undefined or deleted elements

Comment: What use case do you need sparse arrays for?

Comment: @Latheesan: Have you considered using an object (`var answers = {};`) instead of an array?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can count the actual number of keys using `Object.keys(array).length`:

```js
const answers = [];

answers[71] = {
    field: 'value'
};

answers[31] = {
    field: 'value'
};

console.log(Object.keys(answers).length); // prints 2
```

Comment: This works fine for what the OP is looking for, but fails in the case that the array has non-integer properties.

Comment: @torazaburo Not from what I can tell: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/ozXVjY).

Comment: Right, my point is that the OP is presumably looking for an answer of 2 in that case, but gets 3 instead.

Answer (score 3):

By defining index 71, you've told the array that it needs to hold at least 72 entries, and any that you don't explicitly define will hold a value of `undefined`.

To find the number of actual elements, you can iterate through the array and check whether each element is `undefined` or not, and count how many are not `undefined`

Comment: elements can have `undefined` as value.

Comment: Actually, they are **not** "populated" with undefined. They are simply undefined, and there is a difference.

Comment: @torazaburo Better wording?

Comment: I would prefer to say "any that you don't explicitly define will be left undefined". As Nina points out, there is a subtle difference between the array slot HOLDING a value of undefined, and it simply BEING undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You could count it with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var answers = [], count = 0;

answers[71] = { field: 'value' };
answers[31] = { field: 'value' };
answers.forEach(_ => count++);

console.log(count);
console.log(answers.reduce(r => r + 1, 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method which doesn't iterate over deleted or undefined array elements.

```
answers.filter(function(v){ return true; }).length
```

```js
var answers = [];

answers[71] = {
  field: 'value'
};

answers[31] = {
  field: 'value'
};

console.log(answers.filter(function(v) {
  return true;
}).length);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas why this is?

Because that's how the language works.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

> The `length` property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is **always numerically greater than the highest index in the array**.

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-9.4.2):

> Specifically, whenever an own property is added whose name is an array index, **the value of the `length` property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index**;

Notice that it is not true that the length is always one greater than the index of the last populated item. In your case, if you did

```
answers[71] = {field: 'value'};
answers[31] = {field: 'value'};
```

The length would now be 72, but if you then did

```
delete answers[71];
```

the length would remain 72, and **not** be adjusted down to 32.

If your question was actually to find the actual number of populated slots in the array, see the other answers, or you could brute-force it, looping over all indexes up to the length and checking if a slot is populated using the `in` operator:

```
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) count += i in arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use object instead of array and check

```
Object.keys(your_object_like_array).length
```

to get the amount.